# Creating Authentication and Authorization on ASP.NET, with ability to access LDAP 

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap, authorization

So, I've gotten weary with trying to search for my problem online.

I am currently creating an ASP.NET 2.0 application. The application currently is connected to a database which stores all the information I need to store. I also have connection to the LDAP directory at my workplace on it. I am using the LDAP directory for my application as everything is tracked by employee ids. I now need to add authentication and authorization.

Since my workplace is large, I need the ability to limit who has access to the website within the company as well as what they are allowed to do on the website. I know that ASP.NET has some sort of authentication and authorization, but I am completely oblivious as to how it works.

My current solution is to add a table to my database with two columns (employee id and access_id). The employee id can be used to pull information from LDAP about the employee whenever I need to. The access_id is a set of integers that represent what the user is allowed to see on the website.

When the user first starts a session on my website I use their nt id and pull the employee id from LDAP. I then look up all the access_id's and store them in an array for the session. Everytime a user accesses part of the website, I check whether they have the access_id associated with that section and allow or disallow them based on that. My first access_id of 1 allows the user to see the webpage by setting the visibility of  in C# as

```
if(access_id == 1)
  Enter.visible = true;.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't put things like "urgent help needed" in your questions. Everyone here posts questions that are just as important as every other question, and if you need "urgent" help you should perhaps hire a consultant or contractor. It's much better to use those characters to provide a more meaningful title or better question content. Also, it's highly unclear what exactly your problem is, because you have not asked a single question in that entire content. What **exactly** are you asking for help with?

Comment: I was wondering about how authorization and authentication works in ASP.NET. I want to know if I should be using it in my application or not and how would I go about using it.
Also, I am kind of considered as a contracter in the company I'm, so I don't really have resources. Thanks and sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of LDAP directory are you using?  If it's Active Directory, try:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx
or
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405

You could also consider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649313

If it's not AD, you could implement your own MembershipProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

It's better to use the framework(s) where you can and only roll your own code when you have to.

Comment: I believe it is an active directory. Currently, I do not need to add users as they are all in the directory and it is automatically updated in the directory. I just need ability to give roles to the different users and make sure only certain people in the company see it.

Comment: If it is not an AD you can find a generic LDAP Membership- and RoleProvider here: http://code.google.com/p/njupiter/wiki/nJupiterDataAccessLdap.